# How to assign scope in a promise?

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I want to assign a value in my scope into a promise (in an http.get) but my value isn't assign to my scope ! I've tried many things (use $scope instead of this.scope in my controller) but it doesn't work :(

Here is my HTML search input :

```
<input class="searchContent" type="text" placeholder="Type here to search content" ng-controller="searchCtrl as search" ng-keyup="search.typingQuery()" ng-model="search.scope.url">
```

Here is my view for my search page :

```
<div class="bodyContent" ng-controller="searchCtrl as search">

<div class="icon-category categorySearch"></div>
<div class="categoryBar"></div>

{{ search.scope.results }}
```

Here is my JS code :

```
( function()
{

var app;

app = angular.module( 'searchModule', [] );

app.controller( 'searchCtrl', ['$location', '$http', function($location, $http)
{

    var This = this;

    this.typingQuery = function()
    {

        var url = This.scope.url;

        if ( url != '' && url != undefined )
        {
            if ( url == 'profile' || url == 'education' || url == 'skills' || url == 'experience' || url == 'contact' )
                $location.path( url );
            else
            {
                $location.path( 'search/' + url );
                $http.get( '/json/profile.json' )
                    .success( function(data)
                    {
                        var re = new RegExp(url);
                        var results = data.sections[0].body.match( re );

                        This.scope.results = results;
                    } )
                    .error( console.log( 'Error: failed to load json' ) );
            }
        }
        else
            $location.path( 'profile' );

    };

} ] );

} )();
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: what does data look like? Looking in browser console network tab, are requests being made?

Comment: My requests are good, i have my json file in an array, no problem on that side

Comment: and if you `console.log(results)` in success callback?

Comment: For example, if i type : "l", results is equal to : ["l", index: 14, input: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicin… qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."]

Comment: ok so try `This.results=results` then in html `{{results| json}}`

Comment: Nothing happened, but i now have another issue, .success and .error are executed, so i have ["l", index: 14...] and 'Error: failed to load json' ?! (With and without your code)

Comment: suggest you create demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)  Can add a file  `profile.json` to put some sample json in for the ajax call

Comment: I'll do it right now ;)

Comment: It's take long time to adjust my code to Plunker (and i leave in France so it's 3am and i work tomorrow..), i'll do it tomorrow, thank's for your help :)

Comment: It looks like you are making things unnecessarily complicated. Why are you assigning properties to the controller itself rather than just using $scope? $scope works fine in the promises. Here's a stripped down example:  

http://jsfiddle.net/unanT/

Comment: I know that $scope works and it works as this.scope (and maybe better) but i've took habit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found my answer and i now use $scope and a factory to always have my datas on all of my scopes, true 2-ways data binding ;)

Here is my json factory (store my .json in app module to have my datas everywhere) :

```
app.factory( 'jsonFactory', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q)
{
    var factory = {

        jsonData: null,
        jsonFile: function()
        {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http( {method: 'GET', url: '/json/data.json', cache: true} )
                .success( function(data)
                {
                    factory.jsonData = data;
                    deferred.resolve( factory.jsonData );
                } )
                .error( function()
                {
                    deferred.reject( 'Error: failed to load json' );
                } );
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
    return factory;
} ] );

app.controller( 'jsonCtrl', ['$scope', 'jsonFactory', function($scope, jsonFactory)
{
    $scope.jsonData = jsonFactory.jsonFile().then(
        function(data) { $scope.jsonData = data; },
        function(error) { console.log( error ); } );
} ] );
```

And i call my controller jsonCtrl on my body elt :

```
<body ng-controller="jsonCtrl">

    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
```

Now, i can access my data on every scopes like here :

```
app.controller( 'searchCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'jsonFactory', 'resultsFactory', function($scope, $location, jsonFactory, resultsFactory)
{
    $scope.search = {

        url: "",
        searchQuery: function()
        {
            if ( this.url == 'profile' || this.url == 'education' || this.url == 'skills' || this.url == 'experience' || this.url == 'contact' )
            {
                $location.path(this.url);
            }
            else if ( this.url != 'search' )
            {
                $location.path('search');
            }

            var re = new RegExp(this.url);

            resultsFactory.results = [];
            if ( this.url != '' )
            {
                jsonFactory.jsonData.profile.forEach( function(elt)
                {
                    var matched = elt.body.match(re);

                    if ( matched )
                        resultsFactory.results.push( matched );
                    console.log( resultsFactory.results );
                } );
            }
        },
        getResults: function()
        {
            return resultsFactory.results;
        }
    };
} ] );
```

My code to get my datas on a child scope :

```
<div class="bodyContent" ng-controller="searchCtrl">

    ...

    <span ng-repeat="result in search.getResults()">
        {{ result.input }}
    </span>

</div>
```

So, use factories and promises and you'll never have scopes issues ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Angular-land, you don't use "this" very much (which is a relief because it saves constantly having to take a reference to it like "This" or "self" in many cases like we always used to have to do).

Instead, you assign data to your controller's scope and you always have a good reference to this. But you must GET the reference by asking for it. If you don't, $scope won't actually be what you think it is. You'll end up with the classic JS mistake of creating a global variable when you try to put something into it (or throw an exception, depending on what you do).

You must ask Angular to inject $scope into your controller so you can work with it:

```
app.controller( 'searchCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', function($scope, $location, $http) {
    // Now you can safely/correctly use $scope.XYZ here. Note that you typically define
    // both data and functions here:
    $scope.results = '';

    $scope.typingQuery = function() {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

and in your templates, you can simplify them to:

```
<input class="searchContent" ... ng-keyup="typingQuery()" ng-model="url">
```

Note that you also typically don't use the `as` keyword to get to controllers the way you have - it can be done, but it gets confusing quickly and can be hard to debug. You usually wrap something like a search block in an outer DIV layer. When you do, anything inside no longer needs this hack:

```
<div class="search-box" ng-controller="searchCtrl">
    <!-- Search input boxes, outputs, buttons, etc. here -->
    <input class="searchContent" type="text" placeholder="Type here to search content" ng-keyup="typingQuery()" ng-model="url">
</div>
```

It's basically the same but let's you type a little less (as long as your search components are close together).

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your answer but i've already tried this "(use $scope instead of this.scope in my controller)" in my post, but doesn't work. I've tested your method but still doesn't work :(

Comment: It would be best if you posted a sample on Plnkr or jsFiddle. We need a little more than "it doesn't work" to help. :)